# How to aggregate rows with inverse labels?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm working on aggregating thousands of rows of flight data which is structured like so:

[image: o&d pair table]

LGA-LAX and LAX-LGA are both one-ways on a single route, and so I want to combine them into a single row with aggregated values.

The result should look like this:

[image: o&d pair table]

However, I'm not able to do this in either Excel or SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a helper column like

```
=IF(F2 > G2, F2 & "-" & G2, G2 & "-" & F2)
```

and aggregate on that

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IF(F2:F>G2:G, {F2:F, G2:G}, {G2:G, F2:F}), H2:I}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3),sum(Col4) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2 
  label sum(Col3)'',sum(Col4)''"))
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 00]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Power Query` (aka `Get&Transform`) in Excel to do this.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"origin", type text}, {"dest", type text}, {"direct", Int64.Type}, {"connecting", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Sort({[origin],[dest]})),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "-"), type text}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Extracted Values", {"Custom"}, {{"allDirect", each List.Sum([direct]), type number}, {"allConnecting", each List.Sum([connecting]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

It can all be done through the user interface except for the custom column for which the formula is:  `List.Sort({[origin],[dest]})`

[image]